# How to get the number of days in a specific month?

Tags: dart

In the Dart language, how do I get the number of days in a specific month?

Ex:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime(2017, 2, 1); //Feb 2017
```

How do I get the maximum number of days in Feb 2017, for example?

My question is about the Dart language.

Answer (score 17):

```
void main() {
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(now.year, now.month+1, 0);
  print("N days: ${lastDayOfMonth.day}");
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/montyr75/09b5dc9a20ba01955872)

Comment: This should be the answer to this question. It's cleverly solved. Warning though, if the `now.month == 12`, `now.year` should probably have `+1` and `now.month % 12`

Comment: @Albert Dart doesn't add year+1 if month==12. =)

Comment: that's what I mean. I'm not sure if Dart understands that the first of december and the end of the month has to be `now.year+1`.

Comment: Now (2020-06-23) Dart will convert 13 months into January next year.

Comment: For those who don't understand this at first glance like me , the month and day properties of date are indexed by 1, so by setting the date to 0 it treats it as the last day of the previous month.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [date_utils](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/date_utils) package which has the `lastDayOfMonth` method.

Add dependency :

```
dev_dependencies:
    date_utils: ^0.1.0
```

Import package :

```
import 'package:date_utils/date_utils.dart';
```

Then use it :

```
final DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 2);
final DateTime lastDay = Utils.lastDayOfMonth(date);
print("Last day in month : ${lastDay.day}");
```

Result :

> Last day in month : 28

If you don't want to include the package just for that function, here is the definition :

```
/// The last day of a given month
static DateTime lastDayOfMonth(DateTime month) {
  var beginningNextMonth = (month.month < 12)
      ? new DateTime(month.year, month.month + 1, 1)
      : new DateTime(month.year + 1, 1, 1);
  return beginningNextMonth.subtract(new Duration(days: 1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2019, date_utils hasn't been updated for a year and has errors. Instead try the package [calendarro](https://pub.dev/packages/calendarro#-installing-tab-), it's being updated regularly and has what you're looking for.

Follow the instructions in the link above for installation. Implementation looks like this:

```
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = DateUtils.getLastDayOfMonth(DateTime(fooYear, barMonth));
int lastDayOfMonthAsInt = lastDayOfMonth.day;
```

To do it yourself:

```
int daysIn({int month, int forYear}){
  DateTime firstOfNextMonth;
  if(month == 12) {
    firstOfNextMonth = DateTime(forYear+1, 1, 1, 12);//year, month, day, hour
  }
  else {
    firstOfNextMonth = DateTime(forYear, month+1, 1, 12);
  }
  int numberOfDaysInMonth = firstOfNextMonth.subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;
  //.subtract(Duration) returns a DateTime, .day gets the integer for the day of that DateTime
  return numberOfDaysInMonth;
}
```

Modify as needed if you want the datetime instead.

Answer (score 0):

**The below method I belief is correct and avoids edge cases from things like DST.**

**1. First get the start and end date of a month which can be achieved by these functions:-**

As month always starts from 1 we can find start date like this:

```
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = DateTime(currentDateTime.year, currentDateTime.month, 1);
```

Now, getting the last day is a little bit different and can be done like this:

```
DateTime getLastDayOfAMonth({required DateTime currentDateTime}) {
  // Getting the 15th-day date of the month for the date provided
  DateTime fifteenthDayOfMonth =
      DateTime(currentDateTime.year, currentDateTime.month, 15);

  // Converting the 15th-day date to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on date
  DateTime twentiethDayOfMonthInUTC = fifteenthDayOfMonth.toUtc();

  // Getting a random date of next month by adding 20 days to twentiethDayOfMonthInUTC
  // Adding number 20 to any month 15th-day will definitely give a next month date
  DateTime nextMonthRandomDateInUTC =
      twentiethDayOfMonthInUTC.add(const Duration(days: 20));

  DateTime nextMonthRandomDateZeroDayInUTC = DateTime.utc(
      nextMonthRandomDateInUTC.year, nextMonthRandomDateInUTC.month, 0);

  // Now getting the 0th day date of the next month
  // This will give us the current month last date
  DateTime nextMonthRandomDateZeroDayInLocal = DateTime(
      nextMonthRandomDateInUTC.year, nextMonthRandomDateInUTC.month, 0);

  DateTime lastDayOfAMonth;
  if (currentDateTime.isUtc) {
    lastDayOfAMonth = nextMonthRandomDateZeroDayInUTC;
  } else {
    lastDayOfAMonth = nextMonthRandomDateZeroDayInLocal;
  }

  return lastDayOfAMonth;
}
```

**2. Get the dates between the start and end date calculated in step 1 above.**

Now we will find the dates between two dates like this:

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBetweenIncludingStartEndDate(
    {required DateTime startDateTime, required DateTime endDateTime}) {
  // Converting dates provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on dates
  DateTime startDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(startDateTime.year, startDateTime.month, startDateTime.day);
  DateTime endDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(endDateTime.year, endDateTime.month, endDateTime.day);

  // Created a list to hold all dates
  List<DateTime> daysInFormat = [];

  // Starting a loop with the initial value as the Start Date
  // With an increment of 1 day on each loop
  // With condition current value of loop is smaller than or same as end date
  for (DateTime i = startDateInUTC;
      i.isBefore(endDateInUTC) || i.isAtSameMomentAs(endDateInUTC);
      i = i.add(const Duration(days: 1))) {
    // Converting back UTC date to Local date if it was local before
    // Or keeping in UTC format if it was UTC

    if (startDateTime.isUtc) {
      daysInFormat.add(i);
    } else {
      daysInFormat.add(DateTime(i.year, i.month, i.day));
    }
  }
  return daysInFormat;
}
```

**3. Now, use the list provided in step 2 and calculate its length to find the number of dates in the month for the provided date.**

Answer (score 0):

Returns the number of days in a month, according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
This applies the leap year logic introduced by the Gregorian reforms of
It will not give valid results for dates prior to that time. [Official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DateUtils/getDaysInMonth.html)

```
static int getDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
if (month == DateTime.february) {
  final bool isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
  return isLeapYear ? 29 : 28;
}
const List<int> daysInMonth = <int>[31, -1, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
return daysInMonth[month - 1];
}
```